# Why do most fish move fins orthogonally with their axis of symmetry?

Tags: evolution, eyes, ichthyology, marine-biology

So recently I read the question [why are most fishes vertical](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55318/why-are-most-fishes-vertical&ved=0ahUKEwif---r1dfRAhVGhSwKHXmjBykQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNGSEdFWSofZH38NpEto6Y6NttjOUw&sig2=W40cuICMBSWlRFY_w8eSBw) (in the sense of distribution of their body mass) and it got me thinking what is the reason behind the direction they move their fins. My explanation is that they need to catch the image they several times to truly percieve it, so the eyes have to be orthogonal on the direction they move their fins. Am I correct, therefore they swim like this [image: fish swimming axis] rather than this [image: fish swimming vertically]
 because there is more to see on the horizontal dimension in shallow waters?

Comment: Can't see a difference in the two pics?

Comment: @AliceD The waves illustrate the direction of gravity

Comment: The upper fish looks normal, the fish bellow swims breaststroke

Comment: I think it's much more a consequence of the way their muscles are arranged.  Dolphins & whales work perfectly well by moving their flukes vertically.

Comment: @jamesqf Dolphins...haven't thought about them :) Anyway - is there some kind of evolutionary pattern in the way their muscles are arranged?

Comment: @Probably: I really don't know enough about the evolution to do more than guess, but if I had to, I'd guess that somewhere along the line the ancestors of mammals somehow evolved in such a way that it was easier to bend up and down rather than side to side - think of walking movement, then swimming with fins.  Thus when dolphin ancestors started back to the sea, their natural movement was up & down, and that evolved in the direction of improved up & down...

Comment: @jamesqf Oh, you might have got it! Dolphins and whales have to breath and this might be the fastest way to get up / there could be predators

Comment: @Probably: Not quite what I meant.  Think of Tiktaalik http://tiktaalik.uchicago.edu/meetTik2.html crawling out of the water and scrabbling around on its fins.  Carry on through amphibians & reptiles, and you see legs awkwardly splayed out to the sides, with a lot of side-to-side movement (carried to the extreme in snakes).  But somewhere along the line to becoming mammals, creatures got their legs directly underneath them, which allowed more efficient locomotion - think of a horse or dog running.  Now mammals have this new body plan...

Comment: ...and those which go back to the sea have to start evolving better swimming from what they now have, and wound up waving their tails up & down rather than back & forth.  But as I said, this is just me guessing...

Comment: @jamesqf Oh, that's even more cool than I thought, thanks